# Rails 4 - Nested Attributes form only POSTing one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm looking create a system where users join a house, and then can leave notes to other users in their house. Each note should have individual permissions per other users in their house. When a user creates a note, they will be greeted with a form with a text area for the Note content, and then a list of all the other users in the house, with a dropdown indicating that users level of permission on that note.

I'm attempting to use Partials to make things nicer, as Permissions are a polymorphic class and will be used in other parts of our website. Right now, when a Note is submitted as a new note, only one Permission is being POSTed, instead of a Permission for each user, e.g.

```
Started POST "/notes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-03 11:37:47 -0500
Processing by NotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8+fSG6oBsp4C3ikKc6mSNQYIB+mM5w3+42Y5tRVi5LOZY4a1lo0EApLo0WtSVNZ6/MO0yRwGitZzgZWaYR23mg==", "note"=>{"content"=>"okay...", "permissions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"0", "level"=>"3"}}}, "commit"=>"Post"}
```

I've spent a while comparing my View code with partials to others, and can't figure out why it's not submitting a permission for each user. Any advice? I can confirm that the permission that is submitted is created in the NoteController and created in the database correctly. It's just that instead of creating a permission for each user in the list, it's only creating the default permission.

[Note Creation GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGPyv.png)

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new Note..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :permissions do |perm| %>
    <%= render 'permission_new', :f => perm %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_permission_new.html.erb

```
<% House.find(current_user.relationship.house_id).users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render 'permission', :f => f, user: user %>
<% end %>
<% User.new(id: 0) do |user| %>
  <%= render 'permission', :f => f, user: user %>
<% end %>
```

_permission.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.id != user.id %>
<div class="permission">
  <% if user.id == 0 %>
  Default Permission
  <% else %>
<%= user.name %>
<% end %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: user.id %><br />
<%= f.select :level, [["Read Only", 3], ["Read, Edit, and Delete", 1],
  ["Read and Edit", 2], ["Can't Read", 4]] %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

note_controller.rb

```
...
 def new
    @note = Note.new
    @note.permissions.build
  end

  def create
    @note = current_user.notes.build(note_params)
    if @note.save
      @perm_user = @note.permissions.create(user_id: current_user.id, level: 0)
      flash[:success] = "Note Created"
      redirect_to notes_path
    else
      render 'new'
     end
  end
...
  private

def note_params
  params.require(:note).permit(:content, permissions_attributes: [:user_id, :level])
end
```

Comment: can you show controller's code where you're actually performing saving work plus show the `strong parameter` function also because such things occurs due to mishandling of `strong parameters`

Comment: I've updated the main post with the Note_controller code (permission_controller) is empty. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: `params.require(:note).permit(:content, permissions_attributes: { user_id , :level})`

Comment: let me know if it works or not then i'll tell you the main reason in detail

Comment: The exact code that you gave me through an error (unexpected end-of-input, expected keyword_end). I found another stack overflow post where someone used curly braces for their strong params, and the suggested code was this: `params.require(:note).permit(:content, {:permissions_attributes => [ :user_id , :level]})` Which posted the exact same data as what I had before.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone happens to be having the same problem, I figured it out.

```
<%= f.fields_for :permissions do |perm| %>
    <%= render 'permission_new', :f => perm %>
<% end %>
```

f.fields_for only technically creates one field per call. This means that in my _permission_new.html.erb file, where I have a loop creating a dropdown for each user in the house, and a dropdown for the default, all of those dropdowns were linked to the same field, and overwriting each other. Which is why only the last permission was being POSTed when a new Note was submitted. To fix this, you must call the f.fields_for multiple times in your form. In my case, I moved my f.fields_for into my _permission_new partial, and ended up with code like this.

```
_form.html.erb
...
<%= render 'permission_new', f: f %>
...

_permission_new.html.erb
<% House.find(current_user.relationship.house_id).users.each do |user| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :permissions do |perm| %>
    <%= render 'permission', :f => perm, user: user %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% User.new(id: 0) do |user| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :permissions do |perm| %>
    <%= render 'permission', :f => perm, user: user %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```